# How to create custom arrays in fortran?

Tags: cuda, fortran, fortran90

I have been looking at porting a cuda library to fortran. [PGI](http://www.pgroup.com/) and [EM Photonics](http://www.culatools.com/) seem to be two libraries that exist right now. However I have only found what I am looking for over [here](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a3.htm)

```
real, device, allocatable :: adev(:), bdev(:)  ! device declaration
```

So my question is, is there a way to create custom arrays like the code sample mentioned above ? Or is it part of the propreitary compiler from PGI ?

**Edited for further clarity**
In other words can I do this

```
mycustomtype, allocatable :: tmp(:)
```

Comment: By "custom", do you mean arrays in the graphics card memory?  If so, no, there's no standard way to do that in Fortran any more than there's a way to do it in standard C or Java.

Comment: @johnathan dursi, I edited the question a little bit. Can I do as mentioned and use my own allocator ?

Comment: +1 to counter (whatever possible reason someone might have had to downvote this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is standard Fortran. There are several ways to declare arrays; this one in  particular is called declaring a deferred-shape *allocatable array*.

Your best shot would be to check out PGI's documentation under *array declaration*.

Comment: thanks for the answer. My question was can I create something like "real, mycustomtype, allocatable :: tmp(:)"

Comment: @Pavan - Oh, I see. Sorry, I didn't get that. Could I ask you to glance through http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1620298&page=6 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762797/fortran-90-questions-about-array-derived-type and then expand on that. They've put it better than I ever could.