# Can we create custom attributes in fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Expanding on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751000/how-to-create-custom-arrays-in-fortran), I want to know if is possible to create custom attributes in fortran ?

something like this

```
real, custom_attribute, allocatable :: variable(:)
```

If that can be done, I am guessing the following can be done too

```
custom_type, custom_attribute, allocatable :: variable(:)
```

Comment: I think the answer is no - the attributes you are talking about are implemented in the compiler as part of the language specification. But if you tell what you are trying to accomplish perhaps people can suggest another way.

Comment: @thorpe, Thank you for that! It was just a question of interface. PGI was doing something like "real, device, allocatable::var(:)", (device being their custom attribute to denote that the array was on a different device). I half doubted that might be because of their compiler. I can easily use derived types for my purpose. Thanks once again. If you can put that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create user-defined "types".  Probably you can accomplish your goal with this feature.   See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Derived_data_types

Comment: I understand that we can do something like "custom_type, allocatable::variable(:)", I may have asked an idiotic question because I am *very* new to fortran. Can we do something like "real, custon_attribute, allocatable::variable(:)"

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing as custom attributes in standard Fortran. However extending M. S. B.s answer, when using derived data types you can use parameterized derived types, which was introduced with Fortran 2003.
It allows you to define "kind" and "len" attributes for the derived data types.
This enables you to do something like: type(my_type(rk=selected_real_kind(15), extent=size(a))) :: b